# How can I mass delete messages and or purge in Hikari?

Tags: python

I just started coding in hikari and I'm having trouble looking through the docs.
I can't understand how to make my bot mass delete/purge messages.

any help appreciated,

a_twoyearold14

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Mass deleting messages requires two steps:

- Fetching the messages to delete
- Deleting the messages

The former is done using [bot.rest.fetch_messages](https://www.hikari-py.dev/hikari/impl/rest.html#hikari.impl.rest.RESTClientImpl.fetch_messages), which returns a `LazyIterator` across the requested messages. A caveat of the discord API is that messages older than 14 days cannot be bulk deleted - so we are going to limit the return of our `LazyIterator` to the last 14 days only:

```py
# Where channel ID is the channel you are deleting the messages from
messages = (
    await bot.rest.fetch_messages(channel_id)
    .take_until(lambda m: datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) - datetime.timedelta(days=14) > m.created_at)
    .limit(count)  # Limit the messages to the amount you want deleted
)
```

We can then pass the fetched messages into [bot.rest.delete_messages](https://www.hikari-py.dev/hikari/impl/rest.html#hikari.impl.rest.RESTClientImpl.delete_messages) in order to bulk delete them:

```py
# Where channel ID is the channel you are deleting the messages from
await bot.rest.delete_messages(channel_id, messages)
```

You can see a full example using hikari-lightbulb [here](https://github.com/tandemdude/hikari-lightbulb/blob/development/examples/moderation_example.py#L51)